# How to cleanly handle changes to external static files in a django project

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, amazon-s3

Say I've got a django project in a git repo with static files hosted on Amazon S3.  Pretty common setup.  Now there's me and another person working on this project; one is working on the javascript part and I'm working on the python part.  Is there a sensible way to take changes the other person makes to the static files hosted on Amazon S3 and bring them back into the django git project?

Django has a sensible one-way flow for static files: collectstatic grabs all of them and then if you use django-storages it pushes them out to Amazon S3 for you.  But what about the reverse?  How to pull the changed versions of the static files back into the /app/static/ folders in django to keep everything synchronized. I'm not aware of any django functionality.  Multiple git repos?  Something else?

BTW I am using Heroku, if that helps any.

Any suggestions for how to handle this nicely, or am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: are you having a local repository on your computer?

Comment: Yes I have a local repo containing the entire django project.

Comment: If you are working on your own computer & he on his own, where does AWS fits in?

Comment: i am the only one doing deploys to heroku.  we are deploying to heroku to, e.g., test on mobile.  once i deploy, we can both test and makes changes.  all of the changes i make to python are already handled in git.  any changes he makes to static files on AWS currently just _stay on AWS_ and I don't have a nice way to bring them into version control.

Comment: OK evaluate how this looks to you. You create a git repository, then he works on a branch, you evaluate if it works, if it does, merge the branch & push it to heroku.